# How can I study Silverlight programming by using CodeProject website from beginner to pro?

Tags: silverlight

I know that there are many good articles in the CodeProject website.(http://www.codeproject.com/)

However, I can't find a good entrance to start study Silverlight.

Is there an article that lists the good articles that has some kind of order so I can read them to launch my study process?

p.s. I have some C# basics so I do not need to learn from zero.

p.s.s "The WPF / Silverlight Zone" does not help much. It has no reasonable order to show articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just starting out, don't start there. Instead use the tutorials posted on the [silverlight.net](http://www.silverlight.net/learn) site in the learning area - it has literally everything you need to get started, starting with stuff for new people like yourself and going all the way to advanced topics like Out Of Browser and Windows Phone development, as well as illustrating all the latest features of the platform.